# What to do if basketball shoes burns toes and creates water bubbles?

Tags: basketball

I've had these shoes for around 2 years now, and after wearing them frequently they constantly rubs against my pinky toes, making them raw and red. Additionally, they create many water bubbles on my feet, irritating. Without buying another shoe, is there a simple remedy?

Comment: Are you wearing good socks?

Comment: How much do you play?  2 years is _really_ long for shoes that are used frequently - my running shoes when I was running 5km/day lasted 2-3 months, for example. Also - is "water bubble" a blister (a raised bump filled with liquid often caused by repeated rubbing)?